# Get number of certain values from a recordtype

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-structures

I have the following recordtype

```
from recordtype import recordtype

thermometer = recordtype('thermometer', 'sent_level1, sent_level2, name, group')
thermometers =  { 
                 "1A": thermometer(False, False, "t1", "warehouse"),
                 "1B": thermometer(False, False, "t2", "warehouse"),
                 "1C": thermometer(False, False, "t3", "warehouse"),
                 "1E": thermometer(False, False, "t4", "warehouse"),
                 "1F": thermometer(False, False, "t5", "serverroom"),
                 "1G": thermometer(False, False, "t6", "serverroom"),
                 "1H": thermometer(False, False, "t7", "serverroom")
                }
```

I'd like to get the number of items where group = "warehouse"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without thinking about it too hard this works:

```
count = 0
for i in thermometers.values():
    if 'warehouse' in i:
        count+=1
```